# Rank of elliptic curves does not decrease under field extension?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve.

Rank of elliptic curve over quadratic extension $L=K(\sqrt{D})/K$ is calculated by a formula $rank(E/L)=rank(E/K)+rank(E_D/K)$(this is easy to prove).
In particular, rank of elliptic curve does not decrease under quadratic field extension.

But when $L/K$ is a extension of degree $n\ge 3$, does $rank(E/L)\ge rank(E/K)$ always hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the curve has rank $n$, there will be $n$ points on the curve, so that no nontrivial relation (in the sense of group presentations) holds among these points. Vice versa, the existence of $n$ such points implies that the rank is at least $n$.

But relations (since there is no scalar multiplication) do not depend on the field extension.

Comment: To the OP, a concrete way to think about it is this: if you have $n$ points in $E(K)$ that are independent (they have no nontrivial relations in the group law on $E(K)$), how could they possibly acquire a nontrivial relation (become *dependent*) by viewing them in $E(L)$ for a larger field $L$?  When we talk about dependence/independence, it is the same group law no matter what field you're working over.

Comment: The argument is correct, but I disagree with the last paragraph: invariance of rank is a nontrivial property of linear algebra, but here we just have a natural injective homomorphism $E(K) \rightarrow E(L)$, so it cannot decease the rank…

Comment: In field theory, $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbf Q$ but are linearly dependent over $\mathbf R$.  This phenomenon of linearly independent things becoming linearly dependent does not happen with points on an elliptic curve when you talk about rank over a larger field because the term "rank" is about the structure of the rational points as an abelian group ($\mathbf Z$-module), not changing to a module over a larger ring.